# Is C variadic macro able to expand ##__VA_ARGS__ recursively?

Tags: c, gcc, macros, variadic

[variadic macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) mentioned about **VA_ARGS** for gcc.

I did the following experiment.

```
#define EVAL(f,...) eval(f,build_args(args,__VA_ARGS__ , args_end))
```

And

```
EVAL(f,a) // => eval(f,build_args(args,a, args_end))
EVAL(f,a,b) // => eval(f,build_args(args,a,b, args_end))
```

So far so good, but

```
EVAL(f) // => eval(f,build_args(args, , args_end))
```

I must supply at least one argument, I solve the problem according to manual, use '##'.

```
#define EVAL(f,...) eval(f,build_args(args,##__VA_ARGS__ , args_end))
EVAL(f,a) // => eval(f,build_args(args,a, args_end))
EVAL(f,a,b) // => eval(f,build_args(args,a,b, args_end))
EVAL(f) // => eval(f,build_args(args, args_end))
```

So far so good, but

```
#define EVAL(f,...) eval(f,build_args(args,##__VA_ARGS__ , args_end))
EVAL(f,EVAL(g,a)) // => eval(f,build_args(args,EVAL(g,a) , args_end))
```

We can see the second `EVAL` is not expanded, but without '##', the second `EVAL` is expaned.

```
#define EVAL(f,...) eval(f,build_args(args,##__VA_ARGS__ , args_end))
EVAL(f,EVAL(g,a)) // => eval(f,build_args(args,
                  //          eval(g,build_args(args,a , args_end), 
                  //                 args_end))
```

So here is the situation

1. without `##`, I have to supply at east one argument, but macro can be recursively expanded.
2. with `##`, zero argument is OK but macro cannot be evaluated recursively.

Can I have both problems solved at the same time?

Comment: Does it work with indirect macro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you please try this ?

```
#define _build_args(args,f,...) eval(f,build_args(args,__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL(f...) _build_args(args,f,args_end)
```

It seems to work on my side because :

```
EVAL(f,a)
EVAL(f,a,b)
EVAL(f)
EVAL(f,EVAL(g,a))
```

gives :

```
eval(f,build_args(args,a,args_end))
eval(f,build_args(args,a,b,args_end))
eval(f,build_args(args,args_end))
eval(f,build_args(args,eval(g,build_args(args,a,args_end)),args_end))
```

Comment: Yes, it works for me also. Thank you! Your answer is accepted.